# 'EquipmentOrder' object has no attribute 'equipments'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a new e-commerce feature to my python/django project and i keep on getting an error when i use the add to cart button. I am really frustrated because i have been battling it out for weeks now i really need help. Thanks in advance.

here is the EquipmentOrder model

```
class EquipmentOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    equipment = models.ManyToManyField(EquipmentOrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = models.Manager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

here is the add to cart view

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    equipment = get_object_or_404(models.Equipment, slug=slug)
    equipment_order_item, created = models.EquipmentOrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
    equipment=equipment,
    user=request.user,
    ordered=False
    )
    equipment_order_qs = models.EquipmentOrder.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if equipment_order_qs.exists():
        equipment_order = equipment_order_qs[0]
        # check if equipment order item is in order
        if equipment_order.equipment.filter(equipment__slug=equipment.slug).exists():
            equipment_order_item.quantity += 1
            equipment_order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
            equipment_order.equipments.add(equipment_order_item)
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        equipment_order = models.EquipmentOrder.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        equipment_order.equipments.add(equipment_order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
    return redirect("create:equipment_detail", slug=slug)
```

Comment: Post the full traceback

Comment: Since you named the `ManyToManyField` `equipment`, and not `equiments`, it should be `equipment_order.equipment.add(equipment_order_item)`, although renaming the m2m might be a better idea here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the change but now i am getting another error. `Reverse for 'hire_a_crew' not found. 'hire_a_crew' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: i posted another question so please check it out. Thank you.